# Multiple Statements in the Ternary Operator

Tags: java, android

What is the right syntax to have multiple statements in my ternary operator statement?

```
str.length() == 1 ? (str = str.replace(0, str.length(), "00")  && flag = false) : str = str.deleteCharAt(str.length() - 1);
```

I need to execute a couple of statements when the length of my `StringBuilder str` is 1

1. Replace the str with "00"
2. Unset flag

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could just use an if statement.

Comment: Well, the point of writing this statement is to do away with the if else statements. I currently have that bulky logic written.

Comment: Using If else statements will be much more readable code.

Comment: I agree with that. But, is there a way of doing it in a ternary statement?

Comment: yes. I am setting a flag to false if StringBuilder length is 1

Comment: What are you trying to optimize for by writing it in a ternary statement? This looks like an attempt creating code that will confuse you and your coworkers next time you come to read it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK it is not possible. In other languages you can achieve that using the coma operator, but it is not allowed in java.

That being said, doing more than one action in a ternary operation is usually a very bad practice: Yes you gonna save about 4 or 5 lines of code, but it will be way harder to read, edit, and therefore, to debug.

Answer (score 3):

If you absolutely must do it with one ternary operator that's how it can be done :

```
flag = str.length() == 1 ?
    str.replace(0, str.length(), "00") == null :
    str.deleteCharAt(str.length() - 1) != null && flag;
```

Good luck getting it through a code review. As others have suggested, an if statement makes sense here :

```
if (str.length() == 1) {
     flag = false;
     str.replace(0, str.length(), "00");
} else {
     str.deleteCharAt(str.length() - 1);
}
```

Comment: Since `str` is a `StringBuilder`, please drop the `str = ` parts.