# Ternary Operator in java with multiple statements

Tags: java, conditional-operator

I want to write multiple statements in Ternary Operator..But dont know how to write.
I want like this,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String replaceString,newString;
    Scanner user_input=new Scanner(System.in);
    String input=user_input.next();
    boolean choice=true;
    if(choice==true){
        System.out.println("Enter string to replace");
        replaceString=user_input.next();
        System.out.println("Enter new string");
        newString=user_input.next();
        input.replace(replaceString, newString);
        }
}
```

I want to write the above code in java using ternary operator.Please help

Comment: Not sure what you want to do here.  Is there a reason _why_ you want to use a ternary operator (instead of your `if` statement, I assume)?

Comment: I think your question has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33489121/multiple-statements-in-the-ternary-operator

Comment: @andrewjames yes for some reason i want to use ternary operator.

Comment: @kosmičák no this is not my type of question..I want to take input in ternary operator.

Comment: "for some reason" - kind of explanation that doesn't help at all (code does not fit for usage of ternary operator, actually the  only *condition* is doing nothing, the `if` is not doing anything)

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure what you want to do here, or why you want to do it. Also, I will focus on your specific question, and not on your use of `Scanner`.

Is there something about your sample code's `if` statement that you don't like?

*Why do you want to use a ternary operator?*

**Bottom line: I think a ternary operator is a bad fit for what you may be trying to do.**

The Java ternary operator is a one-line way of writing a simplified `if...else...` assignment. In your sample code, you have an `if` but no `else` - and no obvious assignment - unless you mean to assign the result of this line...

`input.replace(replaceString, newString);`

...to a String variable. I may be completely wrong about your intention.

The values of a ternary operator (after the ? question-mark and separated by the : colon) can be assigned by methods, as long as the methods return the expected type.

The following uses a ternary operator:

```
//
// BAD use of the ternary operator - NOT RECOMMENDED:
//
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = userInput.next();
    boolean choice = true;
    String replaced = (choice == true) ? whenTrue(userInput, input) : null;
}

private static String whenTrue(Scanner userInput, String input) {
    System.out.println("Enter string to replace");
    String replaceString = userInput.next();
    System.out.println("Enter new string");
    String newString = userInput.next();
    return input.replace(replaceString, newString);
}
```

You would be better off using `if`, in my opinion.