# Is it possible to do 2 actions with ternary operator In java

Tags: java, conditional-operator

I am trying to make each number 7 to turn into a letter as well. ex:57 75 157
Right now it gives me the word that divided by 7

```
public class Boomtest {

public static int boom () {
    int boom2 = 0;
    String boom7 = "Boombala";{
    for (boom2 = 0; boom2 <= 200; ++boom2) {
    String print = boom2 % 7 == 0 ? boom7 : Integer.toString(boom2);
    
        }
    }
    return boom2;
    
}
```

}

1. Is it possible to do it in ternary?
2. how can I run it without the String print, it feels like I am missing something.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask. It is unclear what you are asking or what you are trying to do. Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description of the problem you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that there are other answers that say NO, like this one: [Multiple Statements in the Ternary Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33489121/multiple-statements-in-the-ternary-operator) but you can use your imagination to do it, for example you can create methods that make the actions, something like this

```
public static int boom(){
    ...
    int numberToDelete = (/*conditional here*/)?actions01():actions02();
    ...
}
public static int actions01(){
    /*Multiple actions here*/
    return 0;
}
public static int actions02(){
    /*Multiple actions here*/
    return 0;
}
```

Anyway I don't recommend you to do that.

PS: Try to correct your identation